# Linq using string.format on a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a string array.

```
var array = new string[] { "test", "test2", "test3" };
```

I am trying to join it into a string with a $ in front of each value in the array see example below.

> $test, $test2, $test3

I have been trying to do this using Linq but so far all of my attempts have failed.

My current attempt

```
var formated = array.Select(a => string.Format("${0}", a)).ToArray();
```

Results in:

> 'Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.'

I know i have done this before but i cant seam to remember how.  I intended to dump formated into a String.Join unless someone has a better idea.

Comment: Just remember most indexes starts at zero, not one.

Comment: With C#6 you can use string interpolation: `array.Select(s => $"${s}")` to avoid such issues

Comment: Would you believe i have been looking at that for 20 minutes.

Comment: @TimSchmelter add that as an answer and i will accept it that's elegant

Comment: Always read error messages carefully, it's all in there: Index (**zero based**) must be...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the wrong index in `String.Format`, indexes are zero based.

With C#6 you can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) ...

```
array = array.Select(s => $"${s}").ToArray();
```

... to avoid such issues

Comment: Thanks for this i knew there was a better way of doing it.  I was even trying foreach at one point

Answer (score 6):

You were close

```
var formated = array.Select(a => string.Format("${0}", a)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too,

```
var newArray = array.Select(x => "$" + x ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using string.format in the linq, why not concatenate strings.

```
var array = new string[] { "test", "test2", "test3" };
var formated = array.Select(x => "$" + x).ToArray();
```

Comment: it is the same answer posted above

Comment: i did not see the answer before posting mine.